# Fix multiple middle mouse click

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Basically I have an issue where the middle mouse button when clicked does multiple very fast middle mouses. For example, if I open a link in a new tab with middle mouse it will open about 10 of that tab. I have tried all of the conventional methods to fix it, ie. driver fixes etc. What I want to try now is a bit of mouse debouncing with AHK (Auto Hot Key) for windows.

Essentially what I am thinking is to do this:

```
while (forever)
    if( capture the middle mouse)
        sleep 500 ms
        mouse click
    end
end
```

Can anyone give some advice with this approach?

Alternatively i thought about making a middle mouse hotkey:

```
$MButton::  
Loop  
{
sleep 500
if not GetKeyState("MButton", "P") 
    break  ; Break out of the loop.
}
send {MButton}
return
```

Can anyone see any problems with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a much simpler solution without a delay. 
This will ignore middle click if the last click was 50 ms ago.

```
#Persistent

global pressed_g := 0 
global delay_g := 50 ; delay in miliseconds, increase this value if your multiple click take longer than delay_g time

return

MButton::
    if( pressed_g = 0 )
    {
        Send, {MButton}
        tooltip,sent
        pressed_g := 1
    }
    SetTimer, Countdown , Off
    SetTimer, Countdown , -%delay_g%

return


Countdown:
    pressed_g := 0
return
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you are looking for this? You press the <kbd>MButton</kbd> and while you keep the <kbd>MButton</kbd> pressed, the script will continue to fire <kbd>MButton</kbd>.

```
#Persistent
MButton::
while GetKeyState("MButton", "P")  ; While the Middle Mouse button key is being held down
{
    Send, {MButton}
}
return
```